# I can't translate this exception. How to fix it?

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting this exception and i quite figure out why this is happening:

```
2013-08-10 06:23:21.417  Unknown class login in Interface Builder file.
2013-08-10 06:23:41.714 [HomeViewController revealMenu]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7145bf0
2013-08-10 06:23:41.716 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HomeViewController revealMenu]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7145bf0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1394012 0x115ce7e 0x141f4bd 0x1383bbc 0x138394e 0x1170705 0xa42c0 0xa4258 0x165021 0x16557f 0x1646e8 0xd3cef 0xd3f02 0xb1d4a 0xa3698 0x2235df9 0x2235ad0 0x1309bf5 0x1309962 0x133abb6 0x1339f44 0x1339e1b 0x22347e3 0x2234668 0xa0ffc 0x252d 0x2455 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

It seems to notify me that the revealMenu method is missing in the HomeViewController, but it's there

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ....
    [self.btnLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(revealMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    ....
}


-(IBAction)revealMenu:(id)sender
{
    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`revealMenu` and `revealMenu:` are two different selectors and you're calling one that doesn't exist resulting in the crash. Replace your code with this and it should work. (added colon at end of selector)

```
[self.btnLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(revealMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The colon specifies an argument, so...

```
-(IBAction)revealMenu
```

Has a selector of `revealMenu` and

```
-(IBAction)revealMenu:(id)sender
```

Has a selector of `revealMenu:` and

```
-(IBAction)revealMenu:(id)sender andSome:(NSObject *)otherArgument
```

Has a selector of `revealMenu:andSome:`